# Full Part/Chapter/Section etc. Hierarchy shown in Autoref (Koma Script 3.2, scrbook)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, autoref

I am writing a long piece of text that is structured into several parts, numerous chapters, etc. In the later part of the document, I need to reference sections etc. that belong to a previous Part, say in Part II of the document I need to reference Part I, Section 1.

However, `\autoref{}` only creates links that are named "Section 1" rather than Part I, Section 1. In other words, it remains unclear to which part the referenced section belongs.

Is there any way to create references that show the full hierarchy of parts, chapters, sections etc?

Many thanks for your support!

Best regards

NP.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, tocindentauto]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{chap:P1chap1}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:P1chap1section1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\label{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsection1} 

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{chap:P2chap1}

\autoref{chap:P1chap1} should look like: I.1

\autoref{sec:P1chap1section1} should look like I.1.1

\autoref{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsection1} should look like I.1.1.1

\autoref{chap:P2chap1} should look like II.1

\end{document}
```

Thanks for all the support so far! However, things got more complicated... :-/ While the referencing works fine in the example, my 'real' document uses some custom numbering for the table of contents. These commands seem to interfere with `\ref{}` command, unfortunately.

Below the updated code, including table of contents and custom numbering:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, tocindentauto]{scrbook}

\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

% ISSUE SEEMS TO BE RELATED TO THESE IN CONJUNCTION WITH TABLE OF CONTENTS
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\def\@prependpart\csname #1\endcsname{%
\thepart.\csname#1\endcsname%
}
\renewcommand{\p@chapter}{\@prependpart}
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\@prependpart}
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\@prependpart}
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\@prependpart}
\let\theHchapterorig\theHchapter%
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\thepart.\theHchapterorig}
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Title Part A}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{chap:P1chap1}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:P1chap1section1}


\section{Section 2}
\label{sec:P1chap1section2}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\label{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsection1}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
\label{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsubsection1}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
\label{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsubsection2}

\part{Title Part B}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{chap:P2chap1}

\ref{chap:P1chap1} should look like: A.I - OK

\ref{sec:P1chap1section1} should look like A.I.1 - I missing

\ref{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsubsection2} should look like A.I.2.1.2 - I missing

\ref{chap:P2chap1} should look like B.I - OK

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good example. Welcome.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{part}.\arabic{chapter}}` along with `\counterwithin{chapter}{part}` from package `chngcntr`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: This destroys the unique `hyperref` anchors, however. The `\renewcommand` is not necessary, since `\counterwithin` uses the format then already, which is `\Roman` for the part counter, but the command changes the full numbering as well, so Chapter I.1 etc. I think only the references are wanted to change this way!

Comment: If things work out for a given question, that's nice. If there are other (non-mentioned) tripwires you saw later, make a new question out of it ;-) Please do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `\counterwithin{chapter}{part}` is prepending the part number everywhere there `\thechapter` is called, so in the ToC and and the chapter header as well as in for every `\thesection` etc.

As far as I have understood only the references should be changed, so `Part 3, Chapter 5` should become `III.5` when being referred to.

This needs a redefinition of the `\p@chapter` and `\p@section` etc. commands, by using an 'argument' grabber, say `\@prependpart` that adds the `\thepart.` output to the references and stores in the `.aux` file at definition time, i.e. the correct part number is frozen for references.

In addition to put `chapter` on the reset list of `part`, this will cause problems with `hyperref`'s hyper anchor system. The hyper anchor for chapter one is usually being called `chapter.1`, but resetting the chapter number for each part, the `chapter.1` anchor isn't unique any longer.

Redefining the `\theHchapter` anchor macro will solve this.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, tocindentauto]{scrbook}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\@prependpart\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \thepart.\csname#1\endcsname%
  }
  \renewcommand{\p@chapter}{\@prependpart}
  \renewcommand{\p@section}{\@prependpart}
  \renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\@prependpart}
  \renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\@prependpart}
  \let\theHchapterorig\theHchapter%
  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\thepart.\theHchapterorig}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{chap:P1chap1}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:P1chap1section1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\label{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsection1} 

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{chap:P2chap1}

\autoref{chap:P1chap1} should look like: I.1

\autoref{sec:P1chap1section1} should look like I.1.1

\autoref{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsection1} should look like I.1.1.1

\autoref{chap:P2chap1} should look like II.1

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update for another numbering scheme**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, tocindentauto]{scrbook}

\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

% ISSUE SEEMS TO BE RELATED TO THESE IN CONJUNCTION WITH TABLE OF CONTENTS
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xpretocmd{\p@chapter}{\thepart.}{}{}
  \xpretocmd{\p@section}{\thepart.\thechapter.}{}{}
  \xpretocmd{\p@subsection}{\p@section}{}{}
  \xpretocmd{\p@subsubsection}{\p@subsection}{}{}
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
    \let\theHchapterorig\theHchapter%
    \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\thepart.\theHchapterorig}%
  }{}
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Title Part A}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{chap:P1chap1}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:P1chap1section1}


\section{Section 2}
\label{sec:P1chap1section2}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\label{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsection1}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
\label{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsubsection1}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
\label{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsubsection2}

\part{Title Part B}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{chap:P2chap1}

\ref{chap:P1chap1} should look like: A.I - OK

\ref{sec:P1chap1section1} should look like A.I.1 - I missing

\ref{ssec:sec:P1chap1section1subsubsection2} should look like A.I.2.1.2 - I missing

\ref{chap:P2chap1} should look like B.I - OK

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great thanks for the quick comments and solution! :-)

Saved me tons of time!

Just one last quick question: is it possible to remove the "chapter", "section", "subsection" from the reference, just showing "I.1" instead of "chapter I.1"?

Comment: @user124612: You're welcome. Please consider to accept the solution later on. Happy TeXing!

Comment: @user124612: Well, why are you using `\autoref` when you don't want the the entity names there? That's what `\autoref` is designed for! Use `\ref` instead of `\autoref` then

Comment: Great! Will do!

Comment: IMHO less complicated: `\makeatletter
\usepackage{xpatch}
\pretocmd{\p@chapter}{\thepart.}{}{}
\pretocmd\theHchapter{\thepart.}{}{}
\pretocmd{\p@section}{\thepart.}{}{}
\pretocmd{\p@subsection}{\thepart.}{}{}
\pretocmd{\p@subsubsection}{\thepart.}{}{}
\makeatother`

Comment: @Schweinebacke: yes, but my way does not need an extra package ;-)

Comment: But it depends on the usage of `\p@…` commands.  Note, that some packages redefine `\refstepcounter`, e.g. `varioref`, to make it possible to use the `\the…` as an argument of `\p@…`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: That's true, but `varioref` is not involved here. In fact, I never used that package for personal purposes

Comment: @user124612: Why the unacceptance? If you did not post the setup you have and did not show the real document it is not really kosher to unaccept the solution that was working for the MWE you posted initially

Comment: Hi Christian, I agree that the proposed solution works for the posted problem! Good job! 

I simplified the 'real' document to the the code that I considered relevant to the problem at hand. Unfortunately, due to my lack of Latex knowledge, I was unaware of any potential interference between the numbering in the table of contents and the referencing. Hence, when I plugged the working solution into my document, I encountered a new problem - so far unknown to me. 

I would appreciate if somebody could help me on this as well :-)

Humble greetings! NP.

Comment: @user124612: See the update at the end of my post, please.

Comment: @user124612 If a answer is a solution for the given example but not for the real document it would be fair to accept it and make a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/should-i-post-a-follow-up-question-or-just-add-more-info-to-an-earlier-question) with a new MWE.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Thanks... For the update I used your proposition. I was thinking to complicated because I answered recently a question where I had to get rid off `\csname thefoo\endcsname`, that's why I defined that grabber. For a mere prepending `\xpretocmd` is sufficient, of course

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Great as well as very timely support!

Apologies from my side, I was not sure how to handle 'follow-up' questions, especially regarding accept/unaccept the initial solution, now I know. :-) 

All the best, NP.